# Create Salesforce Canvas App from war file

Tags: salesforce, heroku-toolbelt, salesforce-service-cloud

So my web application is divided in two modules:

1. UI-module
2. REST-web-services

in UI-module I have Login.jsp which displays a login page in html and authenticates the Login via making POST request call to /authenticateUser service defined in REST-web-services module.

while deploying these two modules I generates a war files (UI-module.war and REST-web-services.war) which then can be deployed on local tomcat server.

So how can I deploy this as a Salesforce Canvas app?
I have gone through the demo example mentioned on https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Let me know if this helps: https://www.jamesward.com/2015/03/10/salesforce-canvas-quick-start-for-java-developers

Comment: Sorry to say that  this doesn't helped me.